# Substitutes for onion and garlic

Tags: onions, garlic

My husband had a heart attack. Quite a few of his medications have a prohibition on both onions (all types including chives, shallots, leeks, spring onions, powders, etc) and garlic. We both enjoy the flavors but I'm not taking any chances with his health.

Is there anything I can substitute for onions and/or garlic that TASTES like either or both of those? I even make his hummus from scratch and it just doesn't taste right without garlic.

Comment: Ask your Dr. about synthetic

Comment: My husband has had a stroke and several heart attacks. None of his medications restrict him from either. In fact, doctors encourage the use of garlic. While health related questions are off topic for this site, I would be curious to know what medications he is taking.

Comment: Identify with your doctor/pharmacist what specifically it is in garlic and onions that would have negative effects (I would guess the organosulfuric compounds), because whatever substitutes you find could potentially have them as well.

Comment: Please don't answer in comments.